# error while loading shared libraries libboost_thread.so.1.54.0

Tags: neural-network, caffe

For anyone having this issue. I was trying to run Long-term Recurrent Convolutional Networks by Jeff Donahue.
https://github.com/LisaAnne/lisa-caffe-public

```
$ soubriquet@ubuntu:/usr/local/caffe/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition$ ./run_lstm_RGB.sh
$ ../../build/tools/caffe: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.54.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed my issue:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libboost* 
$ sudo apt-get purge libboost* 
$ sudo apt-get install libboost1.54-all-dev
```